# Gnome 3: Show all applications of all workspaces?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3

How can I show all currently used application of all workspaces in the Gnome 3 taskbar? In Gnome 2 you were able to right click on the bottom left corner to set this as default behavior but I can't find similar settings in Gnome 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can install and run either the xfce4 panel or the mate panel and do this.  Yes it runs well at the same time as gnome-shell.  Once Wayland hits this might not be the case though.